# Given an array of sum and an array how can to find if all the sums are possible using distinct elements of array?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

example:

if we have array of int as 1 2 3 
and sum array is given 3,3 we can form this sum as {1,2} and {3}
if the sum array is 5 3 we can not create the sum array, we can for {2,3} but not enough items to form the sum 3.

Can someone help me to understand which algorithm can be used to solve the problem.

Comment: What are your approaches?

Comment: i am not able to classify the problem

Comment: have you tried to solve it by brute-force?

Comment: This looks like a generalization of the subset sum problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which $\textsf{NP}$-complete (with one sum to the target and the others to 0). I doubt you will find a good algorithm for it.

Comment: If you want to count the solutions, you need to define how you count it. In your first example, [1+2, 3] is one solution, Is [3, 1+2] another one?